# Owl carousel 2 - custom animation on touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Is it possible to use a custom animation option for mobile devices?

I have used options `animateIn` and `animateOut` with `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`.
This works well, carousel uses this effect when autoplay, but if I try to *swipe* slides, this animation is disabled, and carousel slide like a default one.

```
$('.carousel').owlCarousel({
    mouseDrag:false,
    touchDrag:true,
    loop:true,
    animateOut: 'fadeOut',
    animateIn: 'fadeIn',
    autoplay:true,
    margin:0,
    nav:true,
    dots:false,
    navText: ['',''],
    responsive: {
        0:{
            items:1
        }, 
        600: {
            items:1
        }, 
        1000: {
            items:1
        }
    }
});
```

It looks, like animation options have no effect for `touchdrag`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution might not be ideal but something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qzkz9b5v/) may work:

```
$(".carousel").owlCarousel({
  mouseDrag: false,
  touchDrag: true,
  loop: true,
  animateOut: "fadeOut",
  animateIn: "fadeIn",
  autoplay: true,
  margin: 0,
  nav: true,
  dots: false,
  navText: ["", ""],
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 1
    },
    1000: {
      items: 1
    }
  },
  onDragged: function(e) {
    $(e.target).hide().fadeIn("slow");
  }
});
```

So we tie in to the `onDragged` event and simply hide and fade-in the entire carousel. Do test to ensure it is not buggy, but this might work for you as a kind of stop-gap solution (it isn't the best way as it may simply be masking the underlying transition and that is something you might notice if you flick through quite quickly).

Comment: In my case, this is better, than normal slide. Thanks.